# Multiply all elements of Tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have tensor with 3 elements which I want to multiply with each others.

My code currently looks like this:

```
m1 = tf.multiply(y[0],y[1])
m2 = tf.multiply(m1,y[2])
```

Which imho is very unflexible, of course I could put a loop and iterate over the elements, but I was wondering if there is such functionallity already provded in tf ? I could not find anything in the docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The needed function is called `tf.reduce_prod` and can be found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_prod

Answer (score -1):

use `reduce`

```
import functools
m_final = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: tf.multiply(x, y), your_matrix_list)
```

Comment: Will the functools.reduce function be executed on the GPU ? I am using tensorflow and the GPU for training, and do not want to loose computation time by swtiching between CPU and GPU

Comment: @Kev1n91 You doesn't understand how tensorflow works. When you execute this code, it just adds operations into graph and no calculation at all. Calculation just takes place when you use `sess.run` to run an operation.

Comment: Sure, I am just using it as a backend  in Keras and hat do implement a loss function there. I am still not quite sure wether or not the functions are executed on the GPU or on the CPU when then put into the run session, since the reduce function from functools is not implemented in any GPU code

Comment: @Kev1n91 Actually, almost all the code we type is just adding operations into graph. I mean, what we do is just like drawing a graph, and after drawing the graph, we call `sess.run` to really execute the operations. then all the calculation is handled by tensorflow itself. To be clearer, the `reduce` function executes before any calculation.