# Multiply all elements of PyTorch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I wanted to do something like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064753/multiply-all-elements-of-tensor-in-tensorflow) in PyTorch i.e. multiply all elements with each other keeping a certain axis constant. Does PyTorch has any pre-defined function for this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. [torch.prod](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=prod#torch.prod). Use the `dim` parameter to tell which along which axis you want the product to be computed.

```py
x = torch.randn((2, 2))
print(x)
print(torch.prod(x, 0)) # product along 0th axis
```

This prints

```
tensor([[-0.3661, 1.0693],
           [0.5144, 1.3489]])
tensor([-0.1883, 1.4424])
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to do:
  matrix multiplication, you can use torch.matmul
  multiply a matrix by a scalar ( or tensor with scalars ) you can use torch.multiply

The [tensor](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html) docs are very extensive on that matter... you should take a look